# Not able to change instantiated views dynamically in a NSWindowController in a Bundle project, but able to in Cocoa application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, bundle

**Objective:**

I need to load different views in a windows custom view on drop down selection in a **Bundle Project** for example I have SMS and Email values in drop down and on selecting Email I need to load Email view in a custom view present in NSWindowController and on selection of SMS I need to replace with SMS view in the same custom view.

**Issue**

I am able to successfully load the views in NSWindowController in a **cocoa application project** but when I do the same in the **Bundle project** and **this bundle project is a authorization plugin that runs at login**. Don't why I am getting issue with bundle project. I am pasting error stack trace here

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35d2af53 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6bdf0835 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35d2ada9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 189
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff32fe52c6 -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] + 607
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff32fe5020 -[NSViewController _nibWithName:bundle:] + 174
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff32fe4c05 -[NSViewController loadView] + 134
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff32fe0d5c -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 72
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff32fe0cd9 -[NSViewController view] + 23
    8   SampleBundle                           0x00000001095667e2 $s9SampleBundle8MainFormC17DropDownActionyyypF + 3106
    9   SampleBundle                           0x0000000109567270 $s9SampleBundle8MainFormC17DropDownActionyyypFTo + 80
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff331388d4 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 299
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff33198084 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff33197fb6 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff33197eb8 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 171
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff331c0423 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 96
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff33275532 -[NSPopUpButtonCell _popUpItemAction:] + 101
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff331388d4 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 299
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3318da4e -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 312
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff3318d7ca -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 106
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff331e59c0 -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 114
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff331e5945 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 82
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff331e578c -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 101
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff3315fb20 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 908
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff347fe701 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1419
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff347fdad0 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 338
    25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3481b108 SendEventToEventTarget + 39
    26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3486c0a4 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 368
    27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff348936ce SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 45
    28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff34893673 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 339
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff348934c7 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 96
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff349a1af6 _ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjjPK4RecttjS4_S4_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 1611
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff349a0feb _ZL26_HandlePopUpMenuSelection8P13OpaqueMenuRefP14OpaqueEventRefj5PointtjjPK4RecttS6_S6_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPS0_Pt + 410
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3487485d _HandlePopUpMenuSelectionWithDictionary + 329
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff33358292 SLMPerformPopUpCarbonMenu + 1611
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff331de3ff _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 989
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff331ddf7c -[NSCarbonMenuImpl popUpMenu:atLocation:width:forView:withSelectedItem:withFont:withFlags:withOptions:] + 439
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff33224caa -[NSPopUpButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 604
    37  AppKit                              0x00007fff33195b6b -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 748
    38  AppKit                              0x00007fff330885e9 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 4907
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff32fcbeb0 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2612
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff32fcb23d -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 349
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff32e8f45c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 352
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff33096b9b -[NSApplication _doModalLoop:peek:] + 388
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff33095699 __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke_2 + 64
    44  AppKit                              0x00007fff33095646 __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke + 70
    45  AppKit                              0x00007fff33094ed8 _NSTryRunModal + 100
    46  AppKit                              0x00007fff33094dbd -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 128
    47  SampleBundle                           0x0000000109553def $s9SampleBundle18AuthenticationC3runyyF + 2111
    48  SampleBundle                           0x000000010955405b $s9SampleBundle18AuthenticationC3runyyFTo + 43
    49  SampleBundle                           0x0000000109552e29 -[SampleBundle MechanismInvoke:] + 441
    50  SampleBundle                           0x00000001095531e4 MechanismInvoke + 36
    51  SecurityAgentHelper                 0x00000001066ba506 getLog + 8822
    52  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d10350e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    53  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d10f626 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 87
    54  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d10350e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    55  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d10ebc4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1105
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35c7a460 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35c79baa __CFRunLoopRun + 2370
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35c78fe3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 499
    59  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3480067d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    60  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff348002c9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
    61  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff34800147 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    62  AppKit                              0x00007fff32e85864 _DPSNextEvent + 990
    63  AppKit                              0x00007fff32e845d4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
    64  AppKit                              0x00007fff32e7ed76 -[NSApplication run] + 658
    65  AppKit                              0x00007fff32e7095d NSApplicationMain + 777
    66  SecurityAgentHelper                 0x00000001066bd929 main + 348
    67  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6d1532e5 start + 1
    68  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

**What I have done**

I created two NSViewController swift classes i.e Email.swift and SMS.swift and two xib files Email.xib and SMS.xib and linked Email.swift and SMS.swift as their file owner classes and also linked the view of file owner to the xib file view for both xibs. I also created a NSWindowController class i.e MainForm.swift and a xib file MainForm.xib which has a window and assigned file owner class as MainForm.

**Code from Email.swift NSViewController**

```
class Email: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**Email.xib**

[image: View outlet and class linked]

**Code from SMS.swift NSViewController**

```
class SMS: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**SMS.xib**

[image]

**Code from Mainform.swift NSWindowController**

```
class MainForm: NSWindowController{

   var email: Email!
   var sms: SMS!

   @IBOutlet var DropDown: NSPopUpButton!
   @IBOutlet var CustomView: NSView!

   override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
   } 

   @IBAction func DropDownAction(_ sender: Any) 
   {
        if(DropDown.titleOfSelectedItem == Constants().SMS){
            //clearSubViewsInCustomView is a utility function written to clear the subview
            let _:Int = Utilities().clearSubViewsInCustomView(customView: self.CustomView)
            sms = SMS(nibName: "SMS", bundle: nil)
            self.CustomView.addSubview(sms.view)

        }
        else if(DropDown.titleOfSelectedItem == Constants().EMAIL){
            //clearSubViewsInCustomView is a utility function written to clear the subview
            let _:Int = Utilities().clearSubViewsInCustomView(customView: self.CustomView)
            email = Email(nibName: "Email", bundle: nil)
            self.CustomView.addSubview(email.view)

        } 
    }
}
```

This issue has been bugging me for a while guys, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What’s the exception info in the console say? Make sure You haven’t disabled OS logging to shut it up.

Comment: I would say that's an odd approach to switching view controllers, especially involving a window controller.  You really should let your window controller stay away from the view business since it's not its main job.  I would use one main view controller with container view (`NSContainerView`) that can host either of their children.

Comment: Hi @ElTomato I tried adding `NSContainerView` from Interface Builder but in my project i.e Bundle project( loadable bundle) to be specific an authorization plugin which runs during login, this `NSContainerView` is not even available. When I type in Container view in search views library in xcode 9 it shows nothing, when I try to add programatically it throws an error `Use of unresolved identifier NSContainerView`.

Comment: The only error I could get from console app is that stack trace and I tried crash reports but no report is being generated and I am using `os_log` to print debug messages and they are printing just fine in console. If some setting needs to be enabled in order to generate these crash reports can you tell me how I can do that. @WarrenBurton

Comment: `NSContainerView` aka `NSView`

Comment: What is the path of the nib file in the bundle?

Comment: Those nibs are in the `Bundle.main` i.e when navigated through bundle from terminal the path is Bundle/Contents/Resources that where they lie. @Willeke

Comment: If you want to know why an exception is occuring, then you need to know what the exception is. At the very least, trap it and log it yourself manually.